# show dialog when upgrading database

Tags: android, sqlite

first, i apologize my english is kiddy.

i want to show dialog when upgrading databse.
now i tried creating AsyncTask and put upgrade logic on 'doInBackground'.
and, used to 'preExecute' and 'postExecute' to showDialog.

it seems to good work.
but, it has critical problem.

when user do force close Application (use task killer or task manager), android system is misunderstand every work is well done.

look at this flow

[good work]

databaseVersion = 1;

1. do onUpgrade()
2. execute AsyncTask.
3. onPreExecute(), showProgressDialog.
4. doInBackground(), migrating Database.
5. onPostExecute(), dismissProgressDialog.

databaseVersion = 2;

---

[bad work]

databaseVersion = 1;

1. do onUpgrade()
2. execute AsyncTask.
3. onPreExecute(), showProgressDialog.
4. doInBackground(), migrating Database.
5. **force stop application (use task killer or task manager)**

databaseVersion = 2;

**database migration is not executed completely, but databaseVersion is 2!!**

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: How do you set the new database version?

Comment: just use SQLiteOpenHelper.

Comment: new SQLiteOpenHelper(context, name, factory, version).getWritableDatabase();

Comment: How did you confirm that the database migration was not correctly executed?

Comment: I am glad you did ☺.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When database upgrading, 'onUpgrade()' is called.
and all thing is well done, 'db.setVersion(newVersion);' is called.

below code is in 'SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(boolean writable)'

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    if (version == 0) {
        onCreate(db);
    } else {
        if (version > mNewVersion) {
            onDowngrade(db, version, mNewVersion);
        } else {
            onUpgrade(db, version, mNewVersion);
        }
    }
    db.setVersion(mNewVersion);
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

so, when upgrading is interrupt, database version is not set to new version.